# does g++ with extern "C" really gives the same environment as gcc does?

Tags: gcc, g++, extern

I am writing a code using other packages in C languages and some in C++ langauges. So my code, needs to work with C routines, and C++ classes as well. My plan is, to include all the header files in C with `extern "C" {}` method and use g++ to compile.
So, I copied all the headers in C to a directory and added headers and footers like,

```
#ifdef __cplusplus  
extern "C" {  
#endif  
//...
#ifdef __cplusplus  
}  
#endif
```

However, it still doesn't compile. So I made a mock C program to make it look clear how the problem shows up.

#### main.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <A.h> //This is the problematic header file.
int main()
{
  struct MMM m; //some struct in A.h
  printf("How many times do I have to compile this? %d\n",1000);
  return 0;
}
```

#### A.h

```
#ifndef _A_H
#define _A_H

#ifndef ...
#define ... ...
#endif

#include <B.h>
#include <C.h> 
#endif
```

And it gives me the same error messages while compiling the mock program as the ones during compilation of the real code I was working on. And it is about some preprocessor macro functions defined in B.h and C.h. But I want to assure you all these header files are written inside extern "C" {}. Mock program is written in C language only so I was able to check there is no error messages with gcc and it works great.
So what I am wondering is, doesn't the g++ with extern "C" work just as gcc? Or did I miss something? Is there any suggestions to go around this problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code that produces the errors. C code can usually be compiled by a C++ compiler as-is, but there are some exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

`extern "C"` does not turn a C++ compiler into a C compiler.  The code still has to be valid C++ code.  It cannot use new keywords as identifiers, there is no implicit cast from `void *` to other pointer types, and so on.  `extern "C"` only affects linkage (basically, how the code interacts with other translation units).  It does not change the source language the compiler accepts.